# Date TimeStamp data ttype in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute the following procedure :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE
 PROCEDURE FIX_POD_INDEXED_DOC
   AS
   date1 TIMESTAMP(256);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error(4,19): PLS-00260: Datetime/Interval constraints must be in range (0 .. 9)
```

What is the datatype for **timestamp** in `oracle`?

Comment: TIMESTAMP(n) -> n is the degress of precision in the second fraction and 9 is the MAXIMUM

Comment: Did you try looking [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are specifying `256` where only `0-9` is allowed.

You can only use values between `0-9` in the precision column. Which means if you specify timestamp(2) then `26-JAN-2014 03.00.05.99 PM` will be stored.

Try this:

```
date1 TIMESTAMP;    //Default is 6
```

Or specify fractional seconds to be stored between `0-9` in braces:

```
date1 TIMESTAMP(2);
```

If you want value without fraction of second then specify `0` which will give you value like:

```
26-JAN-2014 03.00.05 PM
```